# Can I change type parameter boundary of generic class within a method?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am facing a generics problem in designing a communication class.

First of all, there are two types of Operation: Query and Mutation. The definitions of each are as follows.

```kotlin
interface Operation<D : Operation.Data> : Executable<D> {
    interface Data : Executable.Data
}

interface Query<D : Query.Data> : Operation<D> {
  interface Data: Operation.Data
}

interface Mutation<D : Mutation.Data> : Operation<D> {
  interface Data: Operation.Data
}
```

These interfaces are in a [library](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/kdoc/apollo-api/com.apollographql.apollo3.api/-operation/index.html), that cannot be changed.

And I can create the following Caller classes for each Query and Mutation.

```kotlin
class QueryCaller<T: Query<Data>, Data: Query.Data, Model>(
    val operation: T,
    val toModel: (Data) -> Model
) {
    suspend fun call(client: ApolloClient): Model? {
        val data = client.query(operation).execute().data ?: return null
        return toModel(data)
    }
}

class MutationCaller<T: Mutation<Data>, Data: Mutation.Data, Model>(
    val operation: T,
    val toModel: (Data) -> Model
) {
    suspend fun call(client: ApolloClient): Model? {
        val data = client.mutation(operation).execute().data ?: return null
        return toModel(data)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to integrate these two Callers in one Caller class that can handle Query and Mutation?

I would like to do like below. But `Operation<Data>` cannot be casted to `Query<Data>` or `Mutation<Data>` because the boundary of `Data` is different from Query.Data or Mutation.Data.

```kotlin
class OperationCaller<T: Operation<Data>, Data: Operation.Data, Model>(
    val operation: T,
    val toModel: (Data) -> Model
) {
    suspend fun call(client: ApolloClient): Model? {
        val query = operation as? Query<Data>
        val mutation = operation as? Mutation<Data>

        val data = if (query != null) {
            client.query(query).execute().data
        } else if (mutation != null) {
            client.mutation(mutation).execute().data
        } ?: return null

        return toModel(data)
    }
}
```

For your information, in Swift, we can separate the call method for Query and Mutation using the `where` clause as follows.

```swift
struct OperationCaller<T: Operation<Data>, Data: Operation.Data, Model> {
    let operation: T
    let toModel: (Data) -> Model

    func call(client: ApolloClient): Model? where T: Query {
        guard let data = client.query(operation).execute().data else { return nil }
        return toModel(data)
    }

    func call(client: ApolloClient): Model? where T: Mutation {
        guard let data = client.mutation(operation).execute().data else { return nil }
        return toModel(data)
    }
}
```

Finally, these example code is a simplified version; actually it is a bit more complex.

Comment: "Operation<Data> cannot be casted ... because the boundary of Data is different": Why not? Sure, it'll give an unchecked cast warning, but it should compile just fine. Just make sure to cast to a valid subtype, so `operation as? Query<Query.Data>`.

Comment: You meant `where T: Query` in your Swift code, right?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks! I made a mistake and fixed the code.

Comment: @Jorn I need to cast to Query<Data> not Query<Query.Data>

Comment: @Yamamoto Well, as you already noticed, `Operation.Data` is not a valid option for the parameter of `Query`. So the compiler isn't going to allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to the Swift code by just writing them as extension functions.

The idea is that extension functions can refine the generic constraints of `T` to either `Query<Data>` or `Mutation<Data>`, whereas in Swift, this can be done inline with `where`.

```
class OperationCaller<T: Operation<Data>, Data: Operation.Data, Model>(
    val operation: T,
    val toModel: (Data) -> Model
) // this can be an empty class

@JvmName("callQuery")
fun <T: Query<Data>, Data: Query.Data, Model> OperationCaller<T, Data, Model>.call(client: ApolloClient): Model? {
    val data = client.query(operation).execute().data ?: return null
    return toModel(data)
}

@JvmName("callMutation")
fun <T: Mutation<Data>, Data: Query.Data, Model> OperationCaller<T, Data, Model>.call(client: ApolloClient): Model? {
    val data = client.mutation(operation).execute().data ?: return null
    return toModel(data)
}
```

Comment: This code caused a compile error `Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature`. Probably these 2 call methods have the same JVM signature. Can you compile this code?

Comment: @Yamamoto Ah I didn't notice that. Just give them different [`JvmName`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname)s.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved the error adding `@JvmName`.